# Print line by line when running a process in python?

Tags: python, loops, printing, multiprocessing

I recently worked on using multithreading but ran into an issue where it seems that multiprocessing would be the better way to go. When I run a simple loop counter function as a process, why doesn't it iterate through the loop and print out the output? Instead the code waits for a set amount of time before producing the output. Is there a way this can be solved or am I stuck dealing with processes this way?

```
import multiprocessing, time

def loop_process(process_name):
    loopCnt = 0
    print "\nstarting {}".format(process_name)
    for loopCnt in range(15):
        print("value of loopCnt = {}".format(loopCnt))
        loopCnt += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    print('stopping {}'.format(process_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    L00P_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop_process, args=('L00P_process',))

    L00P_process.start()
    L00P_process.join()

    print('processes stopped')
    print "Exiting Main"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you're seeing.  On a Windows box just now, running the program from an interactive console ("DOS box"), I saw `value of loopCnt = ...` once per second until the program ended.  That's what I expected.

Which OS are you running under, how are you running the program, and what exactly are you seeing?

On most (all?) machines, standard output (`stdout`) is line-buffered if it's attached to an interactive terminal.  Which means output is forced to display each time a line boundary is hit.  For other kinds of output device, it may use other kinds of buffering, and that could account for a delay.

Something to try:  first add

```
import sys
```

near the top, then add

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

after your

```
print("value of loopCnt = {}".format(loopCnt))
```

That should tell us whether you are, or are not, experiencing a problem with output buffering.

Comment: thank you, I added that and it works fine. I too ran the the program (excluding the `sys.stdout.flush()` in a command prompt and got the predictable behavior. Something must be off with the console used in the Sypder IDE

Comment: Ah, yes, an IDE can confuse things ;-)  If your problem is solved now, you should "accept" the answer; please read here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers